# Expo How to check which app version user installed?

Tags: react-native, expo, app-update

```
 Constants.manifest.version
```

gives me the app version. Is there any way to see the version a user installed or would I need to store it somewhere like db and then always fetch from db and compare it with the version to know if user has an older version installed?

EDIT:
What I am trying to do:

If there was an update, I want to be able to sometimes show a pop up to users that tells them there was an update and potentionally in very few cases i want to then force the user to upgrade. So for that I would need to compare the version the user has installed with the version in the app store/google play and if users version is lower, I send the popup. I would also have some logic to determine if its only a update recommendation or force update. Not sure yet how, but maybe another entry in the db for each version and boolean with boolean forceUpgrade/recommendedUpgrade

Comment: Can you add more detail about what you're trying to do? Are you looking to have logic that runs in the app depending on version, or are you trying to use the installed version for another purpose (like metrics)?

Comment: If there was an update, I want to be able to sometimes show a pop up to users that tells them there was an update and potentionally in very few cases i want to then force the user to upgrade. So for that I would need to compare the version the user has installed with the version in the app store/google play and if users version is lower, I send the popup. I would also have some logic to determine if its only a update recommendation or force update. Not sure yet how, but maybe another entry in the db for each version and boolean with boolean forceUpgrade/recommendedUpgrade

Comment: Can you add the information to the post please? It's important to know how to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

I'm handling version based updates manually, using AsyncStorage and two global constants:

Upon mount, extract storedAppVersion from AsyncStorage. Compare storedAppVersion with hardcoded CURRENT_APP_VERSION, and if there's a change, and if hardcoded RESET_ON_VERSION_CHANGE is true, forceUpdate!

Update occurs

- only the first time the Version changes and
- only if RESET_ON_VERSION_CHANGE is true

after update, store CURRENT_APP_VERSION for subsequent versions (ie. .then() or button press).

```
Conceptual Snippet:


const CURRENT_APP_VERSION 
const RESET_ON_VERSION_CHANGE 
.
.
.

 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDataFromAsyncStorage = async () => {
      try {
        const storedData = await getDataFromAsyncStorage();
        if (storedData) { const { appVersion: storedAppVersion, } = storedData;


      if (storedAppVersion != CURRENT_APP_VERSION) {
        if (storedAppVersion != null) {
          if (RESET_ON_VERSION_CHANGE) {
            deleteEverything().then(() => {
              console.log('DeleteEverything completed');
            });
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    fetchDataFromAsyncStorage();
  }, []);
```